# Magento add/edit product options on frontend

Tags: php, magento

I'm using [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-2.html) extension in order to add and edit products from frontend but the original extension is much limited on the options, so I'm trying to add the Custom options section, is there an easy way to accomplish that? I've found the option.phtml on catalog/product/edit/option in the adminhtml folder and I was trying to copy the code on the frontend template but I think that it's not a good solution.